# C curl/curl.h Error

Tags: c, cgi

I am trying to use curl/curl.h to clean up the URL input, but when I compile I get the following error: "error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘x".

It is tied to the line of code: "char *curl_easy_escape( CURL * curl, char *Buffer, x);" but I am not sure what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <openssl/md5.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp) {

printf("Content-type: text/html\n\n");

char *qPtr;
FILE *fPtr;
unsigned char digest[MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
int i;
char mdString[33];
int x = 0;

if(qPtr = getenv("QUERY_STRING")) {
char Buffer[256];
char *Token;
char username[80], password[80], email[80];
strncpy(Buffer, qPtr, 255); //copy Env variable "QUERY_STRING" into qPtr pointer

//clean up URL
char *curl_easy_escape( CURL * curl, char *Buffer, x);


Token = strtok(Buffer, "&"); //get first query
sscanf(Token, "username=%s", username); //gets value of username field input

Token = strtok(NULL, "&"); //get second query
sscanf(Token, "password=%s", password); //gets value of password field input

//Execute MD5 library on password string
MD5((unsigned char *)&password, strlen(password), (unsigned char*)&digest);

for(i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
     sprintf(&mdString[i*2], "%02x", (unsigned int)digest[i]);
 } //end MD5


 Token = strtok(NULL, "&"); //get third query
 sscanf(Token, "email=%s", email); //gets value of email field input

 //write username, password and email to file
 fPtr = fopen("users.txt", "a+");
 fprintf(fPtr, "%s=",  username);
 fprintf(fPtr, "%s=", mdString);
 fprintf(fPtr, "%s\n", email);
 fclose(fPtr); 

} else { printf("<p>Error: did not get a QUERY_STRING variable."); }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
char *curl_easy_escape(CURL *curl, char *Buffer, x);
```

with:

```
CURL *curl = curl_easy_init();
char *escapedBuffer = curl_easy_escape(curl, Buffer, x);
```

and as The Mask says, your main function should return an `int`.

You should read this:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_escape.html

Answer (score 0):

Remove this function prototype from inside function. It's invalid C code.

```
char *curl_easy_escape( CURL * curl, char *Buffer, x);
```

BTW,you main function should returns an `int`.